# CMD/PS1 runs from prompt but not as a SYSTEM scheduled task?

Tags: scheduled-tasks

At first I tried using the following as a command for a scheduled task (see the full dump of the task below)

```
 C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command C:\Users\knegyesi\Documents\wsl2-network.ps1 *>C:\Users\knegyesi\AppData\Local\Temp\log.txt
```

which *does* start however `wsl hostname -I` comes back empty while it perfectly works from command prompt. Using the full path to wsl.exe doesn't change anything.

I then read to use a cmd or vbs file instead of running the PS1 directly which I did. That, however, doesn't run at all.

I have simplified my case as much as I possibly could. I have reviewed similar questions and either they offer no solution or the solution doesn't work.

I have created a cmd file:

```
echo foo > %TEMP%\log.txt
```

I've created a scheduled task

```
Folder: \
HostName:                             CF3N2Z2
TaskName:                             \wsl2-network
Next Run Time:                        N/A
Status:                               Ready
Logon Mode:                           Interactive/Background
Last Run Time:                        11/15/2021 2:25:52 AM
Last Result:                          0
Author:                               APOLLO\knegyesi
Task To Run:                          C:\Users\knegyesi\Documents\wsl2-network.cmd
Start In:                             N/A
Comment:                              N/A
Scheduled Task State:                 Enabled
Idle Time:                            Disabled
Power Management:                     Stop On Battery Mode, No Start On Batteries
Run As User:                          SYSTEM
Delete Task If Not Rescheduled:       Disabled
Stop Task If Runs X Hours and X Mins: 72:00:00
Schedule:                             Scheduling data is not available in this format.
Schedule Type:                        At system start up
Start Time:                           N/A
Start Date:                           N/A
End Date:                             N/A
Days:                                 N/A
Months:                               N/A
Repeat: Every:                        N/A
Repeat: Until: Time:                  N/A
Repeat: Until: Duration:              N/A
```

And then I did `schtasks /Run /TN "wsl2-network"`

The Task Scheduler GUI reports success. However, the log file is not created. Manually running the script works. I tried adding `@echo off` to make sure the program has no output.

I am completely stuck, I really need this script to run at boot and not at login :(

Comment: Is `%temp%` defined for the SYSTEM user? Try using an explicit filename

Answer (score 0):

Two comments:

First, as noted above by DavidPostill, you shouldn't assume the value
of any environment variable inside a scheduled task, because this is
a limited environment.

Second, `echo` is a command of the Command Prompt (CMD), which
the scheduled task is not running.

It's better to use for a scheduled tasks a `.bat` file, which will
be executed inside an implicit CMD environment.
Remember to use full paths for every executable file that is called,
do not assume the same PATH as in your login.